# Простая анимация в Visual Basic

Tags: анимация, visual-basic

Вот то, что сделал с учётом ваших рекомендаций.

В прошлой версии программы (в моей) у меня работало движение вниз и влево, а потом картинка трясётся!

В этой версии программы у меня есть лишь движение вниз, и то при тряске картинки.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim topryk As Double, downryk As Double, mode As Double, karet As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        mode = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If mode = 0 Then
        ElseIf PictureBox1.Top < 100 Then
            PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top + 4 ''PictureBox1 вниз

        Else : mode = 1
        End If
        If mode = 1 Then
        ElseIf PictureBox1.Left > 930 Then
            PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left - 4      ''PictureBox1 влево
            PictureBox2.Left = PictureBox2.Left - 4        'PictureBox2 влево
        Else : mode = 2
        End If
        If mode = 2 Then
        ElseIf PictureBox1.Left < 960 Then
            PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + 4 'PictureBox1 вправо      
            PictureBox2.Left = PictureBox2.Left + 4  'PictureBox2 вправо
        Else : mode = 3
        End If
        If mode = 3 Then
        ElseIf PictureBox1.Top > 100 Then
            PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top - 4 'PictureBox1 вверх
        Else : mode = 4

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Пункт 3) перечитайте.

Comment: ДА,спасибо,исправил

Comment: @СтудентННГТУ, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно совершать одно действие в зависимости от текущего режима, определять который по состоянию картинок не правильно. Заведите переменную Mode, которую изменяйте по окончании предыдущего режима.

```
If mode = 0 then 
  Mode =1
Else if mode =1 then
  If PictureBox1.Top < 100 Then
    PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top + 4
  else 
    mode =2
  end if 
else if mode =2 then
```

И так далее.

Comment: Я попробовал, не получилось, к сожалению, может, я что-то не так делаю, можете написать мне, как будет это выглядеть применительно к моей программе, исправив ту программу, что я скинул. Если сможете, конечно, спасибо!

Comment: Покажите, как попробовали. Мне с телефона лень набирать.

Comment: Я ИЗМЕНИЛ ТЕКСТ В ВОПРОСЕ(ВПИХНУВ ТУДА ПРОГРАММУ ИЗМЕНЁННУЮ),ТАК КАК В КОММЕНТАРИИ НЕ ПОМЕЩАЕТСЯ!ИСПРАВЬТЕ ПОЖ-ТА,МОЖЕТ В ЦИФРОВЫХ ЗНАЧЕНИЯХ ЧТО НЕ ТАК.ВЕДЬ ДВИЖЕНИЕ ВНИЗ И ВЛЕВО У МЕНЯ И БЕЗ "MODE" РАБОТАЛИ

Comment: Вы написали совсем другое. Добавьте not на верхнем уровне.

Comment: не понял вас?вы исправить можете?

Comment: Я же исправил - добавьте not: if not mode =